# Push method does not work on this Promisse

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, push

I have a problem I have to fill this array to insert it into the database. For each query in the external API it would use Array.push to prepare the array to insert into the Database.
How can I fill this array correctly?

```
Promise.all(arrayPromise).then(result => {      
    Object.keys(allMsg).forEach(function(key) {  
      var ip = key 
      axios({
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "x",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {},
      "processData": false,

      "data": `{"token": "x", "ip": "${key}", "fallbacks": {"ipf":"1"}, "address": 1}`
      }).then(resp => {
      

        var dat = resp.data
        var long = dat.lon
        var lat = dat.lat
        var end =  dat.address
        if (typeof arrayEnd != 'undefined') {
        var arrayEnd = end.split(/\s*,\s*/, 2)
        var state = arrayEnd[0]
        var country = arrayEnd[1]
        
        insertArray.push([ip, long, lat, state, country])
        }
             
    })
    
})
```

Comment: I don't see that `insertArray` is defined within the scope it is called. Also, is it okay for `"address":1` not to have 1 inside quotation marks? "ipf" has the value 1 inside quotation marks so it seems inconsistent.

Comment: Sry this i minimal part of code, ipf is argument for API of geolocation

Comment: I don't understand why the return of array is clear because the asynchronous of promises all

Comment: can you confirm that insertArray is available in this scope of your code?

Comment: What is `allMsg`? Shouldn't you be looping over `result`?

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand. Use `JSON.stringify({"token": "x", "ip": key", "fallbacks": {"ipf":"1"}, "address": 1})`